# Animate CGContextFillRect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a progress view that I'm trying to animate the change in progress. How do you go about doing that? Below is the code to draw the progress.

Thanks in advance

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code.
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // draw the background
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    UIBezierPath *outerPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:0];
    [outerPath addClip];

    CGPoint backgroundStartPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
    CGPoint backgroundEndPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, CGRectGetHeight(rect));
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, _backgroundGradient, backgroundStartPoint, backgroundEndPoint, 0);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    // draw the progress
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    UIBezierPath *innerPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectInset(rect, 1.0f, 1.0f) cornerRadius: 0];
    [innerPath addClip];

    [_glossTintColor setFill];
    CGRect progressRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(rect)*_progress, CGRectGetHeight(rect));
    CGContextFillRect(context, progressRect);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the progress changes, trigger a redraw using `[view setNeedsDisplay];`

See the [UIView reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) on `setNeedsDisplay`.

For example, lets say that custom view you have created has a property called `progress`, the instance variable is called `_progress`. Lets also suppose that property gets updated by some event/timer/additional thread.

```
- (void)setProgress:(float)progress
{
    _progress = progress;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

That overrides the original setter and adds the functionality mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for response. I looked at the reference, but still don't know how to proceed. Can you give an example please?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update. I tried your code, and the animation with UIView animateWithDuration.. block.. That didn't work. The progress is being updated, but without animation. Do I have to use a timer to make the animation work?